# Why does the FixNum#to_s method in in Ruby only accept radixes from 2 to 36?

Tags: ruby, radix

I looked at the documentation and even peeked at the C source, and I can't see why they limited the accepted radixes to 2..36. Anybody know?

Comment: @muistooshort Base 1 exists, ever did a tally list? Or counted the dots some test runners produce for successful tests? For that matter, there's probably a base `1/2` and even more insane stuff (base `phi` anyone?).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As others have pointed out, radix < 2 is troublesome to render. and there's no conventional agreement on what characters to use for radixes larger than ['0'..'9'] + ['a'..'z'], which is why the standard method doesn't support radix outside those limits.

If you really want a custom radix representation, you would need to define the alphabet of symbols to use for the digits.  Here's a little module that will give you the capability.

```
module CustomRadix
  # generate string representation of integer, using digits from custom alphabet
  # [val] a value which can be cast to integer
  # [digits] a string or array of strings representing the custom digits
  def self.custom_radix val, digits

    digits = digits.to_a unless digits.respond_to? :[]
    radix = digits.length
    raise ArgumentError, "radix must have at least two digits" if radix < 2

    i = val.to_i
    out = []
    begin
      rem = i % radix
      i /= radix
      out << digits[rem..rem]
    end until i == 0

    out.reverse.join
  end

  # can be used as mixin, eg class Integer; include CustomRadix; end
  # 32.custom_radix('abcd') => "caa" (200 base 4) equiv to 32.to_s(4).tr('0123','abcd')
  def custom_radix digits
    CustomRadix.custom_radix self, digits
  end
end
```

example use:

```
$ irb
>> require '~/custom_radix'
=> true
>> CustomRadix.custom_radix(12345,'0'..'9')
=> "12345"
>> CustomRadix.custom_radix(12345,'.-')
=> "--......---..-"
>> funny_hex_digits = ('0'..'9').to_a + ('u'..'z').to_a
=> ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
>> CustomRadix.custom_radix(255, funny_hex_digits)
=> "zz"
>> class Integer; include CustomRadix; end
=> Integer
>> (2**63).custom_radix(funny_hex_digits)
=> "8000000000000000"
>> (2**64+2**63+2**62).custom_radix(funny_hex_digits)
=> "1w000000000000000"
>> base64_digits = ('A'..'Z').to_a + ('a'..'z').to_a + ('0'..'9').to_a << '+' << '/'
=> ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "+", "/"]
>> 123456.custom_radix(base64_digits)
=> "eJA"
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the lack of a convention for radixes between 36 and 64 is the reason for the 2..36 radix limitation. Accepted answer for the excellent module and example usage. Thank you!

Comment: How could I _reverse_ this, like to turn `"eJA"` back into `123456`?

Comment: @zac it's atoi with a custom alphabet. for each character, multiply accumulator by base (alphabet size), translate the character to it's numeric and add to accumulator.

Comment: @dbenhur can you please show me what you mean? This is the problem that I have right now.

Comment: Ok! Got it!! `base64_digits.find_index("e")*64*64 + base64_digits.find_index("J")*64 + base64_digits.find_index("A")`

Comment: `radix < 2 is troublesome to render` Is it possible?

Comment: @x-yuri by troublesome, we mean there's no sensible definition for a digit and positional number notation with fewer than 2 digits.  So, if you make some new definition for numeric representations, it may be possible to render, but not with the conventional one.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about ruby, but I know there are 10 decimal digits plus 26 alpha digits.  that's 36.

Comment: That certainly might be why, but there are 46 alphanumeric characters if you differentiate case. This actually came up because I wanted to generate random 31-character strings of that set of 46 characters and was bummed that `31.times.inject('') {|i| i<<rand(46).to_s(46)}` doesn't work.

Comment: @sidewaysmilk But hexadecimal numbers are almost universally case-insensitive, and changing that for higher bases would be horribly inconsistent.

Comment: I suggest you use base-64 encoding instead, then.

Comment: Or if you want to make up your own encoding, create a 46-character string of unique characters, and use the index of the character within the string to determine the digit's value.

Comment: My question isn't really a "how do I..." about the base46 alphabet (`length.times.inject('') {|i| i<<SALT[rand(SALT.length)]}`, where `SALT = [*'a'..'z', *'A'..'Z', *0..9]`). I'm just curious about reason (s) for the 2..36 radix. Thanks, though.

Comment: radix 36 is the highest number that is totally robust:  it is case insensitive, and it fits almost any coding scheme without having to escape characters (think of URLs for one)

Answer (score 1):

How would you render a number in base 1? How would you render a number in base 37? In base 300?

It's conventional to use 0..9 and A..F for hexadecimal numbers. It's intuitive to continue using the alphabet for higher bases, but that only gets you to 36. As there are few uses (if any - I've never seen one) of higher bases, there's no convention for anything beyond that. Except perhaps for base 64, which is a quite different beast, specific to a single base, and not terribly old either. Also, there are a gazillion incompatible variants, which only reinforced my point.

And as for base 1: Unary counting exists, but it's not terribly useful, even less common in computing, and very easy to emulate (just concat `n` times the same character). Besides, people probably have vastly different opinions on what that character should be.